# QGIS change pixel size after multiplication in raster calculator

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, pixel

QGIS change raster size after multiplication in raster calculator:

I have layer with size 25x25 pixel as you can see in the picture:
[image]

When I multiple this layer * 0 in raster calculator (I need clean layer) I get layer with 100x100 pixel size:
[image]

What's wrong? is it bug?

Comment: Did you set "selected layer extent" and checked the number of columns and rows to be the same?